# User Control stuck when ran with Task.Run

Tags: c#, winforms, monogame

I have this user control named ItemControl.

```
public partial class ItemControl : UserControl
{
    public ModuloFramework.ItemSystem.Item Item { get; set; }

    public ItemControl(ModuloFramework.ItemSystem.Item item)
    {
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        InitializeComponent();
        Item = item;
    }

    private void ItemControl_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        itemNameLabel.Text = Item.Name;

        itemTypeLabel.Left = itemNameLabel.Right + 5;
        itemTypeLabel.Text = Item.Type.ToString();

        itemPriceLabel.Left = itemTypeLabel.Right + 5;
        itemPriceLabel.Text = Item.Price.ToString();

        itemDescriptionLabel.Text = Item.Description;
    }
}
```

I have another form, just a test one ofc:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<ModuloFramework.ItemSystem.Item> Items { get; set; }

    private Button EscapeButton { get; }

    public Form1(List<ModuloFramework.ItemSystem.Item> items)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = items;
        EscapeButton = new Button()
        {
            Enabled = false,
            Visible = false
        };
        EscapeButton.Click += (sender, args) => Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CancelButton = EscapeButton;
        int y = 0;
        foreach (Item item in Items) {
            ItemControl control = new ItemControl(item);
            control.Left = 0;
            control.Top = y;
            y += control.Height + 3;
            panel1.Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the context in which the form is called:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
    {
        TestItem.Item1,
        TestItem.Item2
    };
    Form1 form = new Form1(items);
    form.Show();
});
```

What happens when I try to run it, is that the Form1 instance opens, and it gets stuck, whereas the places where the user controls were supposed to be, it shows transparent space, showing the parts behind the it and the game form,
And after a couple of seconds, the form dies.
Reopening the form again causes the same bug

[image: Image of the problem]

What am i doing wrong here?

---

Edit: Fixed code, showing it here in case someone wants to see an example of Erik's fix

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>()
    {
        TestItem.Item1,
        TestItem.Item2,
        TestItem.Item1,
        TestItem.Item2
    };
Form1 form = new Form1(items);
form.Show();
Thread trd = new Thread(() =>
{
    Application.Run(form);
});
```

Comment: `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`?  That's usually a bad thing.

Comment: This is something I came up with from another SO post... Gave it a try, didn't work. I'll make sure to remove it

Comment: Pretty hilarious how the Evil Code is visible right through the window.

Comment: Haha :D As i've said, it was just an attempt... To summon the Antichrist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't create a form from a task. Forms have a message pump which can only operate on the thread they are created. This message pump handles input events, drawing events, etc.

When you run code using `Task.Run` it runs on a threadpool thread. This means that a thread is assigned to run the code, and once it's done that thread is returned to the threadpool and no longer runs any code. Since you're not explicitly running the message pump on that thread then no update events will get processed and the form will act like it's dead.

The simplest thing to do is to create and run the form on the same thread as all your other forms. Barring that, then you should use a `Thread` object to create the form and use `Application.Run(myForm)` on that thread so that its messages get processed.

Comment: Amazing dude, did that job, and I learned a nice thing about Winforms. Thanks!